# Rails: Querying has_one through belongs_to adds PK null in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm getting an error when trying to query a relation. These are my models:

```rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject, inverse_of: :courses
  # This is the important relation
  has_one :department, through: :subject
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department, inverse_of: :subjects
  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :subject
end

class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subjects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The thing is that if I do:

```rb
> Course.where(department: Department.first)
  Department Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `departments`.* FROM `departments` ORDER BY `departments`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Course Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `courses`.* FROM `courses` WHERE `courses`.`id` IS NULL
=> []
```

As you can see, it includes a `WHERE courses.id IS NULL`. I'm able anyway to access this relation by doing:

```rb
> Course.joins(:subject).where(subjects: { department: Department.first })
  Department Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `departments`.* FROM `departments` ORDER BY `departments`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Course Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `courses`.* FROM `courses` INNER JOIN `subjects` ON `subjects`.`id` = `courses`.`subject_id` WHERE `subjects`.`department_id` = 1
```

And I get many objects as result, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something to get this to work.

BTW, if I try to access the method directly, it works correctly:

```rb
> Course.first.department
  Course Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `courses`.* FROM `courses` ORDER BY `courses`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Department Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `departments`.* FROM `departments` INNER JOIN `subjects` ON `departments`.`id` = `subjects`.`department_id` WHERE `subjects`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<Department:0x00007fc40dfab5f8
 id: 1,
 name: "Matemática",
 slug: "matematica",
 code: 1,
 created_at: Sat, 15 Jun 2019 20:49:33 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 15 Jun 2019 20:49:33 UTC +00:00>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think the department is just a little too far removed in the association for `Course.where(department: Department.first)` to work. That's why you need the `join` to explicitly handle the `subjects` intermediary. `Course.first.department` is totally different. It's asking for the department for the first course, not the course that has the first department in the table of departments.

Comment: An off-topic comment: you don’t need `inverse_of` if you are using the default association name. See [*Bi-directional Associations*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations).

Comment: @FranklinYu yes, I know! I just have them because I'm using [`rails_admin`](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) gem for the backoffice, and it tells that it works better if you explicitly set the `inverse_of`. Thank you!

Comment: @lurker It's weird because when you do that in a `has_many`, you don't need to explicitly place the relation

Comment: Sure, in a standard `has_many` you don't need to be explicit. Here you have the indirection of the `has_many` `through` where the other relation is a `belongs_to` if you examine what that means in terms of primary keys, you'll see it's more complicated than a standard `has_many`.